# How to configure fusionpbx if IP changed

Tags: php, sip, voip, freeswitch, fusionpbx

I have a fusionpbx which is working perfect in our LAN with the static local IP. Now we are planing to move this machine to other network where the IP may not be static or also IP will be changed for sure.

What should I do so that it will work as it is working now with the new IP.
I am new to fusionPBX, So sorry if it is a simple question.

Thanks

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Well you need to set a static IP according to the network.Or you can assign that machine a dynamic dns hostname and point all your telephones to that hostname

Answer (score 1):

If you can not get a static IP the only option is to assign the machine a dynamic dns hostname.
Go to dyndns.org and get a free hostname
Next on your freepbsd machine install ddclient (follow [THIS](http://www.enavigo.com/2007/08/08/installing-dynamic-dns-client-on-freebsd/) instructions)
Than point all your telephones to that hostname.

You should also be a little more specific on what the machine is doing right now.

Answer (score 0):

Change the FusionPBX's domain to a dynamic DNS hostname, that you update with the current IP address.

Also remember that all users are per domain.  So if you change the server's IP before changing the domain, then you will need to login as: admin@Old_IP/Domain